# How do I match one of several possible strings?

Tags: sql-server, regex, sql-server-2008-r2

How would I match one of several literal strings? For example, `this`, `that` or `other`?

I am trying `[(this)(that)(other)]` but it seems to be returning anything that matches any of the characters, not the whole strings. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: @dawg thanks, why doesn't it work with the brackets?

Comment: @dawg, that will also match `thisthat`

Comment: @ArmanSchwarz, brackets indicate that Regex should search for the characters inside the bracket.

Comment: @pcnThird isn't that what I want to do?

Comment: @ArmanSchwarz, I should have said *individual* characters, instead.

Comment: If you are trying to match those exact set of strings in a query, why wouldn't you use something like `WHERE field IN ('this', 'that', 'other')` or if you are trying to to match those substrings use a series of `LIKE` filters? I don;t see where you need overhead of regex to achieve what you are looking to do.

Comment: @pcnThird: Yes, perhaps `\b(this|that|other)\b` then. [See it work](http://regex101.com/r/yN3uH5)

Comment: @dawg, works perfectly. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want only "this" "that" or "other"

You could use the regex that dawg is using.

Your problem will be that that regex will also match "thisthat".

For that you need to use word bounderies!

Try This instead :

(\bthis\b|\bthat\b|\bother\b)